# Should I use select("column_name") or select(column_name) with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to use `select` from `dplyr` for selecting columns. However, I am confused whether I should use `""` or just directly column names.

For example, both methods give the same result:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% select(cyl) # method 1

mtcars %>% select("cyl") # method 2
```

Do `""`s matter at all in this case? Is there a case (packages, `shiny` etc.) where it is dangerous to use one of this methods?

Comment: Perhaps https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html could give you some insights on this topic?

Comment: @MartinGal this webpage does not really explain my question. :)

Comment: According to `?select`: You should use unquoted expressions separated by commas. You will find more information with `tidy selection` link is provided there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. It only matters if you use it to select from a vector, where it gives you a warning. Other than that - no difference.

Example with a vector:

```
df <- data.frame("a"=1:10,"b"=letters[1:10],"c"=11:20)
my_columns <- c("a","c")

# With warning
df_subset <- df %>% select(my_columns)
# Without warning
df_subset <- df %>% select(all_of(my_columns))
```

Comment: `mtcars %>% select(c("cyl", "mpg"))` does not give any warning